# Referential transparency and guard

Tags: haskell

From [Learn You a Haskell for great good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) I got:

```
ghci> [1..50] >>= (\x -> guard ('7' `elem` show x) >> return x)
[7,17,27,37,47]
```

I changed the example to:

```
ghci> [1..50] >>= (\x -> if x > 25 then [] else [()] >> return x)
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
```

So far so good. But now I want the other 25 numbers:

```
ghci> [1..50] >>= (\x -> if x > 25 then [()] else [] >> return x)

<interactive>:204:2: error:
    • No instance for (Num ()) arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the expression: 1
      In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘[1 .. 50]’
      In the expression:
        [1 .. 50] >>= (\ x -> if x > 25 then [()] else [] >> return x)
```

I can work around it like so:

```
ghci> [1..50] >>= (\x -> if x < 26 then [] else [()] >> return x)
[26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]
```

My question is the following: I thought that because of referential transparancy I could replace the guard with an if ... then ... else clause. By proof of the above examples, it seems to work except for the case when "[()]" is first in the clause. Why is this? I try to get a deeper understanding of what is going on here. I am interested in the mechanics of Haskell. This feels inconsistent somehow. I am very interested in your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this fails is because now the compiler reads this as:

```
(\x -> if x > 25 then [()] else ([] >> return x))
```

This is important since the `else` part will return a list of `Int`s (so `[Int]`) here, whereas the `then` part will return a list of a "unit" type `()` (so `[()]`) and of course these two do not match. Since an `if`-`then`-`else` should return values of the same type on both the `then` and the `else` clause, it thus says that unless `()` is a `Num` type (such that it can parse `1` and `50`, etc. to that type), we have a problem.

so the `>> return x` is part of the `else …` clause. By adding brackets, you can obtain the same result:

```
(\x -> (if x > 25 then [()] else []) >> return x)
```

For example:

```
Prelude> [1..50] >>= (\x -> (if x > 25 then [] else [()]) >> return x)
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
Prelude> [1..50] >>= (\x -> (if x > 25 then [()] else []) >> return x)
[26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. It makes sense to me.